# UIScrollView includes extra space at bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView which continually adds extra space at the bottom of its scroll area on iOS 7. If I rotate the device, the problem fixes itself, however, before rotating after first navigating to the view controller, the extra space always appears. I've included an image below:

[image]

What I've tried:

1. Set `automaticallyAdjustScrollViewInsets` to `NO`
2. Checked `contentSize`, `contentOffset` and `contentInset`. All appear fine.

I'm not sure what else to try to solve this issue, and would greatly appreciate any help or direction here!

Edit: As another layer of complexity to this issue... I call a method, `updateScrollViewContentSize` in my `viewDidAppear:` method. When I rotate, and it somehow fixes itself, this same method is called. So my `contentSize` is being set when my view appears and when I rotate.

To make things worse, the content size is always set to 638... Whether there is extra space or not. But, for some reason, the scrollView ignores this until we rotate.

Here is the method to update the `contentSize`:

```
- (void)updateScrollViewContentSize {
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, (self.feedbackFooterView.frame.origin.y + self.feedbackFooterView.frame.size.height + 20))];
}
```

Comment: are you used storyboard for that or it's added by coding itself?

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: Its added manually by code, and I am using autoLayout.

Comment: any luck with this issue ??